# How can you combine videos with different resolution into single HLS video?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

HLS breaks videos up into multiple short segment (.ts) files. Each of these segments can have different metadata. So, for instance, you can have the resolution change mid-way through a video, and the player can adapt to this. I have videos of varying aspect ratios (and thus different resolutions) that I would like to stitch together into a single HLS video. Note, I do not want to simply letterbox everything and combine it into a single video with one resolution.

I am currently using ffmpeg, so solutions using this are preferred.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 8216](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216#section-4.3.2.3):

> **4.3.2.3.  EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY**
>
> The EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag indicates a discontinuity between the
> Media Segment that follows it and the one that preceded it.
>
> Its format is:
>
> #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
>
> The EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag MUST be present if there is a change in
> any of the following characteristics:
>
> - file format
> - number, type, and identifiers of tracks
> - timestamp sequence
>
> The EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag SHOULD be present if there is a change in
> any of the following characteristics:
>
> - **encoding parameters**
> - encoding sequence

On client behaviour:

> The encoding parameters for samples in a Media Segment and across
> multiple Media Segments in a Media Playlist SHOULD remain consistent.
> However, clients SHOULD deal with encoding changes as they are
> encountered, for example, by scaling video content to accommodate a
> resolution change.  If the Variant Stream includes a RESOLUTION
> attribute, clients SHOULD display all video within a rectangle with
> the same proportions as that resolution.